# IONIC 3: How to read free storage capacity of mobile phone?

Tags: ionic3

Well, I need to know the current free space from Android or iOS. Is there anyways that I can read the free space?

I need to store data into folder so I need to make sure there are still free space. If not, I will take another action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but a quick Google shows that the [@ionic-native/file](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) might be what you need to use.  From the documentation:

`getFreeDiskSpace()`
Get free disk space in Bytes

Returns: Promise Returns a promise that resolves with the remaining free disk space in Bytes

Comment: Thanks! I'll give feedback later..need to try first.